# Laravel Accessor Pivot Table in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to Calculate of Total from `Backend` in Laravel 6 using `Accessor` By following code Below...

```
  // Sale Model

   protected $appends = ['grand_total'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class)->withPivot('quantity', 'discount', 'unit_price');
    }

    public function getGrandTotalAttribute()
    {   
        foreach ($this->products as $product) {
            return $this->pivot->unit_price - ($this->pivot->unit_price * $this->pivot->discount) * $this->pivot->quantity;
        }
    }
```

I got an error when try to access it from api

> Trying to get property 'unit_price' of non-object

Please give me any idea?? Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, Suddenly i manage to make it work by change `$this` to `$product`

```
   public function getGrandTotalAttribute()
    {   
        foreach ($this->products as $product) {
            return $product->pivot->unit_price - ($product->pivot->unit_price * $product->pivot->discount) * $product->pivot->quantity;
        }
    }
```